# How can you create a paging effect in JS similar to the iOS home screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css, ipad

I am trying to create a website for tablet with a navigation where the user swipes between pages. The site will be viewed only on iOS devices.

I have tried one approach where I move the page in relation to the touch location, then on touchend scrollLeft the container to the page position. 
Here is the code

```
$(function() {
  var xScreenStartPos, xScrollStartPos;
  xScrollStartPos = 0;
  xScreenStartPos = 0;
  $(document).on('touchstart', '.page', function(e) {
    xScreenStartPos = $(this).parent().scrollLeft();
    xScrollStartPos = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
  });
  $(document).on('touchmove', '.page', function(e) {
    var deltaX, xPos;
    e.preventDefault();
    xPos = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
    deltaX = xScrollStartPos - xPos;
    if ((deltaX > 50 || deltaX < -50) && scrollingVertical === false && menuOpen === false) {
      $(this).parent().scrollLeft(xScreenStartPos + deltaX);
    }
  });
  $('.page').on('touchend', function() {
    var previousPage;
    previousPage = void 0;
    $('.page:in-viewport').each(function() {
      if ($(this) !== previousPage && $(this).offset().left < 512 && $(this).offset().left > -511) {
        $(this).parent().animate({
          scrollLeft: $(this).parent().scrollLeft() + $(this).offset().left
        }, 250);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

However this approach is very jittery and feels sluggish. It doesn't feel like a smooth user experience. What I am trying to replicate is the smooth navigation similar to swiping between pages on the iPad home screen.

I know it will never be the same as the native experience, but am trying to get as close as possible. Can anyone please help point me in the direction of a better solution?

Comment: http://stereobit.github.io/dragend/

Comment: Do you have JSFiddle/Codepen link for this ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try [swipejs](https://github.com/thebird/Swipe). The swiping effect is really close to native, and it has a very good api.